# Mako "Missing parentheses in %def"

Tags: python, pylons, mako

In trying to add a cached section to a Mako template, I get the error listed in the above question. Adding `()` to the end gets rid of the error, but I see no content on my page. Any help is appreciated!

```
<%def name="test" cached="True" cache_timeout="60" cache_type="file">
    Test
/%def>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was not aware that `<%def>` defines a function. If I use the parenthesis and call the function via `${test()}` right after definition, it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you be using parantheses while defining the `def` test.
Also if the "cached" etc. are parameters then I think your 
your definition should be something like below:

```
<%def name="test(cached='True',cache_timeout='60',cache_type='file')"> 
    Test 
/%def>
```

Also see the [Mako documentation](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/defs.html)

Comment: I did of course look at the Mako documentation. This example is almost directly from there.

http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/caching.html

I get the impression you're just guessing.

Comment: I've used Mako, but not in the context of generating web pages and hence wasn't aware of the caching and the modalities involved with it. I had just answered thinking that you are missing the parentheses (which are used in def definitions) and putting them would fix the issue. But I was wrong :(